# Why is self-implemented quicksort faster than internal quicksort?

Tags: php, big-o, quicksort

Being a mostly PHP developer (and self taught), I've never really had a reason to know or understand the algorithms behind things like sorting algorithms, except that quicksort is on average the quickest, and it's usually the algorithm behind PHP's sort functions.

But I have a pending interview coming up soon, and they recommend understanding basic algorithms like this one. So I broke open http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ and implemented my own QuickSort and Partition functions, for practice of course, for sorting an array by one of it's values. I came up with this (I'm using PHP 7.1, so a fair bit of the syntax is relatively new)

```
function Partition(array &$Array, $Column, int $Low, int $High): int {
    $Pivot = $Array[$High][$Column];

    $i = $Low - 1;

    for ($j = $Low; $j <= $High - 1; $j++) {
        if ($Array[$j][$Column] > $Pivot) {
            $i++;
            [$Array[$i], $Array[$j]] = [$Array[$j], $Array[$i]];
        }
    }

    [$Array[$i + 1], $Array[$High]] = [$Array[$High], $Array[$i + 1]];
    return $i + 1;
}

function QuickSort(array &$Array, $Column, int $Low = 0, ?int $High = null): void {
    $High = $High ?? (count($Array) - 1);

    if ($Low < $High) {
        $PartitionIndex = Partition($Array, $Column, $Low, $High);

        QuickSort($Array, $Column, $Low, $PartitionIndex - 1);
        QuickSort($Array, $Column, $PartitionIndex + 1, $High);
    }
}
```

And it works! Awesome! And so I thought, no real point to using it, since there's no way the PHP interpreted version of this algorithm is faster than the compiled C version (like what would be used in usort). But for the heck of it, I decided to benchmark the two approaches.

And very much to my surprised, mine is faster!

```
$Tries = 1000;
$_Actions = $Actions;

$Start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $Tries; $i++) {
    $Actions = $_Actions;
    usort($Actions, function($a, $b) {
        return $b['Timestamp'] <=> $a['Timestamp'];
    });
}
echo microtime(true) - $Start, "\n";

$Start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $Tries; $i++) {
    $Actions = $_Actions;
    QuickSort($Actions, 'Timestamp');
}
echo microtime(true) - $Start, "\n";
```

This gives me consistent numbers around `1.274071931839` for the first one and `0.87327885627747` for the second.

Is there something silly that I'm missing that would cause this? Does `usort` not really use an implementation of quicksort? Is it because I'm not taking into account the array keys (in my case I don't need the key/value pairs to stay the same)?

---

Just in case anyone wants the finished QuickSort function in PHP, this is what I ended up with, which sorts arrays by column, descending, in about half the time as the native `usort`. (Iterative, not recursive, and the partition function was also inlined)

```
function array_column_sort_QuickSort_desc(array &$Array, $Column, int $Start = 0, int $End = null): void {
    $End = $End ?? (count($Array) - 1);

    $Stack = [];
    $Top = 0;

    $Stack[$Top++] = $Start;
    $Stack[$Top++] = $End;

    while ($Top > 0) {
        $End = $Stack[--$Top];
        $Start = $Stack[--$Top];

        if ($Start < $End) {
            $Pivot = $Array[$End][$Column];

            $PartitionIndex = $Start;

            for ($i = $Start; $i < $End; $i++) {
                if ($Array[$i][$Column] >= $Pivot) {
                    [$Array[$i], $Array[$PartitionIndex]] = [$Array[$PartitionIndex], $Array[$i]];
                    $PartitionIndex++;
                }
            }

            [$Array[$End], $Array[$PartitionIndex]] = [$Array[$PartitionIndex], $Array[$End]];

            $Stack[$Top++] = $Start;
            $Stack[$Top++] = $PartitionIndex - 1;

            $Stack[$Top++] = $PartitionIndex + 1;
            $Stack[$Top++] = $End;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many entries does `$Actions`have?

Comment: @NineBerry In this specific case, 198.

Comment: @NineBerry If I give it 20183 elements for a single try I get `0.24767899513245` and `0.15674591064453` respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the difference between the arguments you pass to your `QuickSort` and those you pass to `usort()`.  `usort()` has a much more generic interface, which operates in terms of a comparison function.  Your `QuickSort` is specialized for your particular kind of data, and for performing comparisons via the `>` operator.

Very likely, then, the difference in performance is attributable to the much higher cost of evaluating function calls relative to evaluating individual `>` operations.  That difference could easily swamp any inherent efficiency advantage that `usort()` might have.  Consider, moreover, that because it relies on a comparison function written in PHP, `usort()`'s operation involves running a lot of PHP, not just compiled C code.

If you want to explore this further then consider modifying your implementation to present the same interface that `usort()` does.  I'd be inclined to guess that `usort()` would win an apples-to-apples comparison with such a hand-rolled variation, but performance is notoriously hard to predict.  This is why we test.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. I even started to, in my mind, try to plan out how to write a full usort-style function and it got complicated real quick. So I guess now I just have a faster way of sorting a key-less array by a column :)